# Plotting multiple individual correlation plots using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation, scatter

That is gonna be a very basic and naive question, but as my R and programming skills are very limited, I have no idea how to solve it. I would really appreciate if you guys could help me on this.

I want to plot multiple correlation plots comparing a fixed x-axis (Sepal.Length, in the example below) with each column on my dataset as y-axis (Sepal.Width, Petal.Length and Petal.Width). I suspect I might need to use apply, but I don't know how to build it in a function.

Right now I am able to do it manually one by one, but that is not helpful at all. Bellow, I am sharing the piece of the code I would like to apply to every column in my dataset.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=Species)) + 
geom_smooth(aes(group = 1), method=lm,) + 
geom_point(size=4, shape=20, alpha=0.6)  + theme(legend.position="none") + 
annotate(x=min(iris$Sepal.Width),y=min(iris$Sepal.Width),hjust=.2, 
label=paste("R = ", round(cor(iris$Sepal.Width, iris$Sepal.Width),2)), 
geom="text", size=4)
```

After generating all plots my idea is plot all of them side by side using grid.arrange package.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking something like this?

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

iris %>% select(-Species) %>% 
  gather(YCol, YValue, -Sepal.Length) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=YValue)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(YCol~.)
```

[image]

It contains same `Y-axis` but if you do not want, then you could use `scales="free_y"`.

Comment: Hi Prradep, thanks a lot for the comment. It definitely seems to be an option, but I am still facing some issues. The first one is that I am plotting 12 graphs and the using facet_grid attribute is plotting all in the same column making each one shrinks and out of scale. The second is that I don't know how to plot the correlation coefficient for the different plots.  tried to use the same YValue parameter you used in ggplot but I get an error. Last and easier to fix (but not for me), when I tried to use the factor Species to set different colors I got an Aesthetics error. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: Please update the question with the details if it is related to this question. If not, then ask a new question accordingly. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)